# Quickblox: I am receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address"mem-address") when joining/leaving chat rooms

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, quickblox, dealloc

Hey so the title gives some information, but let me expand further. In my iOS application, I am receiving this EXC_BAD_ACCESS message when I am joining and leaving chat rooms quickly (by selecting a thread in a UITableView and view is getting pushed to a new UIViewController and then popping back to the UITableViewController). I am trying to fix this problem because it is more prevalent with slower network connections, and I want to avoid crashes. I use the Quickblox Chat service based on the ChatService.h/.m files that are in the sample-chat xcode project. Here is the only modified code:

```
- (void)chatRoomDidEnter:(QBChatRoom *)room{
    if (self.joinRoomCompletionBlock) {
        self.joinRoomCompletionBlock(room);
        self.joinRoomCompletionBlock = nil;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kNotificationChatRoomDidEnter"
                                                    object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

The crash happens at the end of this method and when I turned on NSZombies, I got this error message:

```
*** -[QBChatRoom retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15e6bbe0
```

I am actually calling these methods from that ChatService in my UIViewController's viewWillAppear/Disappear methods (written in Swift):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.chatRoom = self.dialog.chatRoom
    ChatService.instance().joinRoom(self.chatRoom, completionBlock: { (joinedChatRoom : QBChatRoom!) -> Void in
        //joined
    })
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)  {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self);

    if (self.chatRoom != nil) {
        ChatService.instance().leaveRoom(self.chatRoom);
        self.chatRoom = nil
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight with this issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you and have no idea how to solve it. I tried saving all chatrooms that are in the process of joining inside an Array in a 'manager' object which seemed reduce the occurrence of this crash significantly but i'm still getting it at times. On a separate note, I don't think you need to explicitly leave a chatroom as QB will automatically do it once the chatroom object is deallocated.

Comment: That's funny that you say you don't think you need to explicitly leave a chatroom because to prevent crashing, I just took out leaving the chatroom in viewWillDisappear. It caused no noticeable problems. Also, to prevent crashing in joining a room, I added a check to see if self.joinRoomCompletionBlock is not nil (see the code in the above chatRoomDidEnter method), which the provide code from Quickblox did not have.

Comment: I've also got a check to see if self.joinRoomCompletionBlock is not nil (same as you), but still getting the crash every once in awhile. It's very seldom but still getting it nonetheless. Unable to reproduce it reliably though...

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Swift yet, but I would guess that

```
ChatService.instance().joinRoom(self.chatRoom, completionBlock:{...})
```

is asynchronous (thus the completion block) and is not retaining self.chatRoom.

When things are quick as you describe, viewWillDisappear is called first and self.chatRoom becomes nil. Later, the completion block is called and "room" (or self.chatRoom) attempts to retain, but it is too late.

self.chatRoom is released before the completion block is called and thus you have your zombie.

Is there an abort call of some kind in ChatService?

Comment: There is no abort call that I can find in the Quickblox documentation, at least for QBChat. The closest thing I found was this http://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/Classes/QBQuery.html#//api/name/cancel but it seems like it's not available for Chat calls. Do you think it is possible to check that self.chatRoom is NOT released before leaving the room?